# Troubles installing Mingw bin folder

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-code, g++, mingw

I am trying to use Mingw to get a c++ compiler and debugger in VS Code. I am following this popular tutorial: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/cpp/config-mingw

My problem is when I download and install the latest version of Mingw-w64 (from this site: https://www.msys2.org/), the `bin` folders are empty. Essentially it is installing the Mingw on my C drive and then I change the path variable to match the folder destination of the Mingw `bin` folder, but the `bin` folder is empty every time I download it. If I am correct, in the `bin` folder there should be all the .exe files (`c++.exe`, `g++.exe`, `gbd.exe`, etc etc). Where do I get the proper .exe files and when I download Mingw how do I fix the empty `bin` folder?

Comment: It should install to: `C:\msys64\mingw64\bin` unless you changed the default.

Comment: Did you install MinGW-w64 through MSYS' package manager `pacman`?

Comment: I know where the bin folder installs too. The folder just installed with nothing in it. I have not tried ‘pacman’ , could you explain further?

Comment: pacman is MSYS2's package manager, you can use it to install MinGW-w64 in MSYS2's bin folder.
If you don't need MSYS2, but just a standalone MinGW-w64 you could consider using the standalone build from https://winlibs.com/